# Finding volume of water that emerges from opening per unit time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure

A rectangular opening (width w and height h2-h1) is cut into the side of an open tank. The water doesn't emerge in a uniform velocity.
Assume that SA of tank >> area of opening.

I'm trying to study for a final and this was on a past exam. Please help on how to solve this! I know Pressure/Bernuoulli's is involved, and the continuity equations should also be used right?

[image: image of tank]

Comment: Hello ikim, and welcome to Physics SE! Note that this is not a homework help site; questions of this nature should be labelled with the tag 'homework-and-exercises', and should show some attempt to work through the problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since rate of flow should be a function of height, v = sqrt(2gh). So would h simply be h2-h1?

Comment: $h$ is whatever it is. At any given point, $h$ takes some value between $h_1$ and $h_2$. So start by thinking about the pressure on the wall of the tank as a function of $h$ (ignoring for the moment the fact that there's a hole in the tank).

Answer (score 1):

How would you solve this for a single small hole? What happens if you now move that hole down by a small amount? What if you add up the contributions of all these holes?

Congratulations, you just integrated the expression for the flow rate over the aperture.